# How to parse data which starts with an array [?

Tags: json, parsing, swift3

So in my swift 3 xcode project, I want to parse some data using JSOmN by consuming a web service called "http://tour-pedia.org/api/"
And the data within it for example is set like this:

```
[
    {
     "address": "Science Park 904",
     "category": "attraction",
     "id": 30884,
     "lat": 52.355320008998,
     "lng": 4.9574317242814,
     "location": "Amsterdam",
     "name": "Dakterras Science Park",
     "originalId": "4d8b3370bc848cfa1043ea2b",
     "polarity": 0,
     "subCategory": "Scenic Lookout",    
    },
   {
     "address": "Science Park 201",
     "category": "attraction",
     "id": 30661,
     "lat": 52.356701093273,
     "lng": 4.9529844809109,
     "location": "Amsterdam",
     "name": "In 'de Natuur' rondom Science Park",
     "originalId": "4da2ede7c6e96ea85e1ede5d",
     "polarity": 0,
     "subCategory": "Field",  
     }
]
```

I want to use the address, location and name field.

so far i have done this:

```
func fetchInfos(){

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://tour-pedia.org/api/")!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest){ (data,response,error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        do{

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]


        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }

    }

}
```

but i don't know how to continue on from here.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let us assume your string s is the json with sqaure brackets 
String s = "[{\"a\":\"b\"}]";

s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
//do all your processing on s now, as the sqaure brackets will be removed !!